# Правильный способ построения set и get методов в случае вложенных классов

Tags: ооп, архитектура, uml

Здравствуйте. Никак не могу определиться с определением set и get методов класса Property.

[image: UML Диаграмма]

Класс Property представляет собой реализацию пары "ключ-значение", которая должна быть записана в файл. Эта пара имеет такой вид - Key: value1, value2, ...

PopertyView отвечает за то, как Property будет записываться в файл.

PropertyType представляет собой "ключ".

PropertyValue придеставляет собой "значение".

Для PropertyType и PropertyValue реализовано много разнообразных set методов, но чтобы с их помощью изменить поле key или value из класса Property get методам нужно возвращать ссылку на эти поля. Но общее назначение set и get заключается в защите данных от нежелательных изменений. А раз я буду возвращать при помощи get метода ссылку, то какой вообще смысл в set и get методах? Тогда уж проще сделать поля public.

Если отказаться от возвращение ссылки по get методам, то единственным способом вызова set методов из классов PropertyType и PropertyValue будет создание их аналогов в Property, но если классов будет больше, это может превратиться в целый зоопарк set методов.

Как поступить в данной ситуации?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Я решил эту проблему, просто отказавшись от фанатичного определения полей как private. Соответственно, отпала необходимость в сеттерах и геттерах. Теперь я использую их только для того, чтобы преобразовывать поля класса в другие классы. Например так

```
public class simpleClass {
    public int minutesInt = 100;

    public Date getDate() {
        Date date = new Date();
        date.setMinutes(minutesInt);
        return date;
    }

}
```

Пользуюсь этим подходом уже почти год и недостатков пока не заметил.

Answer (score 2):

Боишься boilerplate code в виде кучи ненужных setter и getter'ов ? воспользуйся библиотекой [lombok](http://jnb.ociweb.com/jnb/jnbJan2010.html).

А вообще getter и setter, на мой взгляд, изжили свое, если code style не запрещает, то в тех местах, где от них можно избавиться, лучше это сделать. Например, для final полей не обязательно создавать getter.

Comment: Спасибо, но хотелось бы получить ответа, который не привязан к конкретному языку.